# Application manifest file for window service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services

I've added a manifest file to the windows service project and enabled the administrator access node, but I'm not getting any admin access popups.

And I'm consuming this window service in my windows application and every time starting the application in administrator mode to do operations on window service (like installing using installutil.exe and starting and stopping using ServiceController).

Is it make sense by adding a manifest file for window service project? required to install, uninstall, start, pause and stop the service as window services requires admin privileges to do any kind of operation related to it.